# Help with Lua Patterns

Tags: lua

Why this doesn't works

```
local filepath = "Name : Java DB 10.5.3.0 Vendor : Sun Microsystems, Inc Install Date : 20110429 Version : 10.5.3.0"
local name,vendor,installdate, version = string.find(filepath,"^Name : (.*?) Vendor : (.*?) Install Date : (.*) Version : (.*)$")

print(name)
print(vendor)
print(installdate)
print (version )
```

Need to break the string using Regex:-

I have a string  below

```
"Name : Java DB 10.5.3.0   Vendor : Sun Microsystems, Inc   Install Date : 20110429   Version : 10.5.3.0"
```

I need to get the `Vendor :Sun Microsystems, Inc`

I need to get the `Install Date :20110429`

I need to get the `Version :10.5.3.0`

**Input string**  to Regex

```
local strname = "Name : Java DB 10.5.3.0   Vendor : Sun Microsystems, Inc   Install Date : 20110429   Version : 10.5.3.0 "
```

**output string**

```
Name :Java DB 10.5.3.0
Vendor :Sun Microsystems, Inc
Install Date :20110429
Version :10.5.3.0
```

Comment: Do You want to replace with regex and generate a new string, or just capture name, vendor, install date and version?

Comment: Is your "output string" correct?  It only shows the labels, not the actual values (contrary to your description), so I'm a bit confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: just capture the name , vendor , install date and version from the above string

Comment: I need to separate/ break  the  main string in substring  Like I need from the main string substring like Name,Vendor,Install Date and Version

Comment: just capture the name , vendor , install date and version from the below string

Comment: local strname = "Name : Java DB 10.5.3.0 Vendor : Sun Microsystems, Inc Install Date : 20110429 Version : 10.5.3.0 "

Comment: local strname = "Name : Java DB 10.5.3.0 Vendor : Sun Microsystems, Inc Install Date : 20110429 Version : 10.5.3.0 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't understand Your output, but the following regex may be a start on what You might want. [Visualized here](http://regexr.com?2ujeh)

```
^Name : (.*?) Vendor : (.*?) Install Date : (.*?) Version : (.*?)$
```

Comment: Or as well a greedy version: `^Name : (.*) Vendor : (.*) Install Date : (.*) Version : (.*)$`

Comment: local filepath = "Name : Java DB 10.5.3.0 Vendor : Sun Microsystems, Inc Install Date : 20110429 Version : 10.5.3.0"
                                                                      local name,vendor,installdate,version =  string.find(filepath,"^Name : (.*?) Vendor : (.*?) Install Date : (.*?) Version : (.*?)$")                                                          
print(name)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lua, but...  "string.find() returns the start and finish indices of the whole pattern and then captures" [See](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial). So, the return of the string.find does also return two indices that You don't include... Try `local iStart,iEnd,name,vendor,installdate,version = string.find(...`

Comment: local iStart,IEnd,name,vendor,installdate,version = string.find(filepath,"^Name : (.*) Vendor : (.*) Install Date : (.*) Version : (.*)$")
Log:Info(name)
Log:Info(vendor)
Log:Info(installdate)
Log:Info(version )

Comment: better to use string.match if you don't want the `start` and `end` variables.